# Expression for a k-form $\omega$ written locally

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

Expression for a k-form $\omega$ written locally

Page 303 John Lee Introduction to Smooth Manifolds First Edition:

In any smooth chart, a k-form $\omega$ can be written locally as:

$\omega = \Sigma'_I \omega_I dx^{i^1} \wedge .... \wedge dx^{i^k}$

Where $\Sigma'_I$ is taken over all the increasing multi-index's [edit] of length k.

Where the coefficients $\omega_I$ are continuous functions defined on the coordinate domain.

I was just wondering if somebody could explain to me why it is necessary to sum over all increasing multi-index's [edit] of length k. I think the reason that I am confused is that an earlier result showed that $\{\epsilon_I$ | $I$ is an increasing multi-index of length k $\}$ is a basis for the vector space of alternating co-variant k-tensors.

Is it strange that the summation defining a k-form locally goes over ALL the increasing multi-index's [edit] of length k? What is the connection here between the basis for the alternating co-variant k-vectors and the index of summation in expressing a k-form locally? I'd appreciate any insight in general, thanks!

Comment: Isn't that just linear algebra? That is $\{v_1, \cdots, v_n\}$ is a basis of a vector space, then every element are of the form $\sum_i a_i v_i$

Comment: No, no, no, you're just misinterpreting. He means (and should have said in there somewhere) that $I$ represents increasing multi-indices *of length* $k$. After a while, it's tacitly understood.

Comment: After Ted's comment I think I understand your confusion (and I second his comment).

Comment: @TedShifrin The OP has made an edit.

Comment: Mushroom, I'm confused. Why shouldn't you expect to have to take (locally) a linear combination of all the basis elements? In any coordinate chart, you're applying the basis result for $\Lambda^k(\Bbb R^n)^*$.

Comment: Ted, my thinking was completely wrong. I understand what is going on now, it's hard to say what exactly my thinking was and why it was wrong because it was so very wrong. Thank you again for your patience.